# Curly brace with a bar next to it

Tags: braces

I'm trying to work out if there's a symbol for this, or if my hack will have to do.

What I'd like to achieve is a symbol identical to the curly braces with a bar here:

[image: (Asymmetrically) Encrypted Term]

But the closest I can seem to get is this:

[image: (Asymmetrically) Encrypted Term]

which clearly leaves a small space, as it's actually just

```
\{\!|\ Term\ |\!\}
```

I've tried to draw it into detexify but it's not come up with anything. (The top screenshot is from a LaTeX PDF, but I can't find the .tex file for it anywhere unsurprisingly.)

Any help or suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: i know these are in the stix fonts, but don't remember the name, and it's not easy for me to check at the moment. they're definitely in unicode.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, according to http://www.stixfonts.org/allGlyphs.html it is `02983  5745  RU  stixgeneral.otf  ⦃   LEFT WHITE CURLY BRACKET` and there are another 4 possible.

Comment: You can try with `\{\kern-2pt|\ Term\ |\kern-2pt\}`

Comment: @salimbou: thanks, that's perfect (well, I've changed it to -2.5pt and that looks about as good as I think it's going to be! Post this as an answer and I'll accept it, if nothing better is presented?

Comment: @Sigur: & barbarabeaton: Thanks; how would I include this in a LaTeX doc? I'm using XeLaTeX.

Comment: @Savara Better use `\mathopen{\{\mkern-10mu|}` with whatever distance you choose. Using `\mkern` is alwas better than `\kern` because it scales well. In any case I would define a macro `\specialset{ \textit{Term} }_{\textit{Term}}^{A}` for instance.

Comment: Did you try The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List? [ftp://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a simple MWE to obtain what you want

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\lbbar}{\{\kern-0.5ex|}
\newcommand{\rbbar}{|\kern-0.5ex\}}

\begin{document}

\[ \lbbar \ Term\ \rbbar^A_{Term} \]

\end{document}
```

If you want to make yours brackets stretchable, you can use the `scalerel` package which provide `\stretchleftright` command, it can be used like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand{\lbbar}{\{\kern-0.5ex|}
\newcommand{\rbbar}{|\kern-0.5ex\}}

\begin{document}

\[\stretchleftright{\lbbar}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n i}{\rbbar}\]

\end{document}
```

Which gives

[image]

Comment: `ex` is a unit of vertical measure.  much better to use a unit of horizontal measure (`em`, or `mu` in math).  while many fonts are "square" (uniformly sized in both directions), some aren't (like computer modern bold), and they will scale differently when placed into a subscript, for example.